# jQuery How to get height of div after content change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm changing content of div dynamically, and I need to get it's new height right after the change.

```
var text='Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla ';
$('.jspPane').html(text);
$('.jspPane').ready(function()
{
  alert($('.jspPane').height());
});
```

For example this code will give me **2376**

But when I call `$('.jspPane').height();` in Google Chrome console it gives me **90** which is the right value for this text.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Sincerely, Stan

Comment: Place the `alert` outside of `$('.jspPane').ready(function()`, just after `$('.jspPane').html(text);`. The `.ready` method is for registering functions to be called when the DOM was loaded: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @FelixKling Right but my Chrome shows the correct value even with not needed here `ready` block: http://jsfiddle.net/f2tR2/.

Comment: @VisioN: Mmh, right... but in the OP's case we don't know when the code is actually executed.

Comment: @FelixKling Then IMO the right answer could be to place this code (of course without `ready`, but it doesn't really matter though) in the DOM `ready` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `.html()` inside `.ready()`.

```
var text='Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla Bla-bla-bla';

$('.jspPane').ready(function()
{
     $('.jspPane').html(text);
     alert($('.jspPane').height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.jspPane').html(text);
alert($('.jspPane').height());
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mckr4/)**

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work! That's why I tried to use 'ready' function

Comment: @stan31337: You should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo yourself...  obviously it works without `.ready`, so if it does not work for you, you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: How can I know why other users are downvoting you? `:P` ;)